# 'Random' "Program received signal SIGABRT: Process abort signal." Error

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90, fortran77

I have a large program (many modules, subroutines) and receive the error "Program received signal SIGABRT: Process abort signal." The odd thing about this error is that it occurs maybe e.g. 19/20 times I run the seemingly identical code (I noticed this as it ran the first time, then if I try quite a few times it does run once in a blue moon). 19/20 times I get the SIGABRT error.
The things I've changed from the code are essentially passing through a few slightly large arrays down through modules and subroutines 'top down' in the model.

- When I pass them down but do not use them at all in calculations, it runs.
- When I pass them down and do use them in seemingly innocuous ways I get 19/20 times this error. And for some reason large values in an array I set to zero in the code almost only a few lines before. (Thus it seems it is getting values from somewhere else and assigning them wrongly)

The randomness of the errors, i.e. that it mostly doesn't work, but sometimes the code runs just fine is really odd to me, and also I'm guessing it is memory/new passed down arrays related. Does anyone know what might cause such a thing/how to reduce memory e.g. if there's a sort of 'deallocate' for non-deallocatable arrays such as:
real (kind=dbl_kind), dimension (20,20,5) :: my_array? Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you compiled and run with all run time checks turned on - `-fcheck=all` for gfortran? And are they all *exactly* the same run that fail? i.e. same executable, same inputs? Does the load on the host machine vary from run to run - i.e. are other significant processes running?

Comment: Do you get any other error message apart from SIGABRT? Can you quantify roughly how much memory you are using? Assuming Linux what does `top` tell you? But please do the runs with -fcheck=all first

Comment: Looks like a memory overflow, but without seeing the code it's very difficult to comment. Apart from the suggestion of @IanBush, did you try running the program with a debugger?

Comment: If you are on linux, try running with electric fence or valgrind.  That may tell you roughly where the leaks or violations are.

Comment: If you are on *nix, set ulimit to unlimited and make sure you have a /var/core directory.  When it core dumps, use coredumpctl to find out where it has crashed.